# Is it possible to omit set-cookie header from the response in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that certain actions need to retutn just xml or json and they shouldn't send the cookie stuff that's intended for browsers. AFAIK it's a use case for metal in Rails 3 but is it possible with 2.3? Except at the Rack level...