# How to remove Set-Cookie header from response in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some actions that respond with static content. I also need them cached on client.

Similar question was asked in the past for rails 2

[Is it possible to omit set-cookie header from the response in Rails 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129436/is-it-possible-to-omit-set-cookie-header-from-the-response-in-rails-2-3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the built in option.

```
env['rack.session.options'][:skip] = true
or
request.session_options[:skip] = true
```

or in older versions use this

```
env['rack.session.options'][:defer] = true
or
request.session_options[:defer] = true
```

You can find the documentation for it here http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Abstract/ID.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Remove charset from Rails content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433059/remove-charset-from-rails-content-type) or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#setting-custom-headers

Hope this would help.